# How to send Select2 AJAX POST with body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am using select2 with ajax. The data needs to be fetched using a POST request with some payload in the body.

POST request is being sent but the data is urlencoded and sent as request payload instead of request body.

I am trying this:

```
self.$("#elem-id").select2({
placeholder: 'Placeholder Text',
allowClear: true,
ajax: {
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'my_url',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function(term, page) {
        return {
            q: term,
            q2: [{
                "hello": "world"
            }]
        };
    },
    params: {
        headers: getHeaders(),
        contentType: "application/json"
    },
    quietMillis: 250,
    results: function(data, page) {
        return {
            .....
        };
    },
    cache: true
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Pass the object you return in the done function through `JSON.stringify` function

```
data: function(term, page) {
    return JSON.stringify({
        q: term,
        q2: [{
            "hello": "world"
        }]
    });
},
```